# Any faster way to replace substring in AWK

Tags: bash, awk, substring

I have a long string of about `50,000,000` long... , and I am substituting it part by part

```
cat FILE | tail -n+2 | awk -v k=100 '{
        i = 1
        while (i<length($0)-k+1) {
            x = substr($0, i, k)
            if (CONDITION) {
                x changed sth
                $0 = substr($0,1,i-1) x substr($0,i+k)
            }
            i += 1
        }
        gsub(sth,sth,$0)
        printf("%s",$0) >> FILE
    }'
```

Are there any ways to replace `$0` at position `i` with `x` of length `k` without using this method?

The string is too long and the commands runs extremely slow

```
sample input:
NNNNNNNNNNggcaaacagaatccagcagcacatcaaaaagcttatccacAGTAATTCATTATATCAAAATGCTCCAggccaggcgtggtggcttatgcc

sample output:
NNNNNNNNNNggcnnncngnnnccngcngcncnncnnnnngcnnnnccncNGNNNNNCNNNNNNNCNNNNNGCNCCNggccnggcgnggnggcnnnngcc
```

If substring with length `k=10` contains `>50%` of `A || a || T || t`

(so there are `length($0)-k+1` substrings)

substitute `A` and `T` with `N`, `a` and `t` with `n`

The `$0` string must maintain it size and sequence (Case sensitive)

### EDIT:

I misunderstood the requirement of this problem, and repost the question at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63912078/faster-algorithm-language-for-string-replacement).

Comment: As per your edited question string is 50 million long?(characters or lines?), does this mean you are saving output of a whole huge file into a variable, that shouldn't be done, awk is capable of reading Input_file so we could directly read it. Request you to please do add sample of input and expected output to make question more clear, cheers.

Comment: It is a `.fa` file with 50 million character, which I had to substitute substring with certain condition without changing other things. I tried my best to think of a better algorithm for this problem

Comment: `at position i with x of length k` I do not understand. Which position `i`? What should the result be? What is the input? Does `x` has length `k`? Also what is `CONDITION`? `if (CONDITION)` will always false. `50 million long` Does each line has 50 million characters or there are many lines and the count of characters of input stream has 50 million characters?

Comment: `25 of this file contains >80%` so more then 20? `substitute them with N` So how it that "position " and "x of length k" related? Is this an "example" of parameters?

Comment: yes, but the actual length of substring would be `100` in my case

Comment: ? Please specify that in your question.... Why not say it's 100 from the start? Do you want to round up or down (or don't care)? Ie. the length of substring `99` should count 79 or 80 characters? I see many lowercase letters in input and some uppercase. Is the match of `A` or `T` case sensitive? Is it going to be one long line of 50 milion characters?

Comment: @hey0god, Still not clear, please spend sometime in your question. Post correct samples of Input_file and expected output along with Logic of how to get expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Does the case-ness of input matter? Ie. can we convert it all to lowercase and just care about lowercase? Does the input has one long line of 50 milion characters or there are multiple lines with length sums up to 50 miliion characters?

Comment: It is case-sensitive, substitute upper case with upper case, lower case with lower case

Comment: Hi, could you give a clear example of what you want. Give a string of 20 chars. assume `k=5` and tell us what you want to happend. I have the feeling that the script above is doing something which is not what you actually want. But with examples, we might help you out.

Comment: I provide a sample input and output now, the problem cannot be too specific, or I may get into trouble

Comment: Would input `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` result in `nnnnnnnnnnaaaaa` or `nnnnnnnnnnnnnn`? Ie, is the window of 10 characters scanned on the input before or after replacement to n is done? Will there be `n` or 'N` characters in the input?

Comment: scan before the replacement is done, there are `N` characters in the input

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be `NNNNNNNNNNggcnnncngnnnccngcngcncnncnnnnngcnnnnccncNGNNNNNCNNNNNNNCNNNNNGCNCCNggccaggcgnggnggcnnnngcc`? (One `a` near the end differs. There are no 5 `aAtT` near it...)

Answer (score 1):

Basically:

- read a window of characters to two buffers - scratch buffer and output buffer
- if in the scratch buffer there are more then some count of characters `ATat`

  - then replace all characters `ATat` in the output buffer buffer to `Nn` respectively
- output one character from the output buffer
- flush one character in both buffers
- and go to step 1 to repeat reading the characters into buffers
- when the end of line is encountered, just flush output buffer and reset it all

A small C program for sure is going to be the fastest:

```
// The window size
#define N        10
// The percent of the window that has to be equal to one of [AaTt]
#define PERCENT  50

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// output a string
static void output(char *outme, size_t n) {
    fwrite(outme, n, 1, stdout);
}

// is one of [AaTt]
static bool is_one_of_them(char c) {
    switch(c) {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
        case 'T':
        case 't':
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Convert one of characters to n/N depending on case
static char convert_them_to_n(char c) {
    // switch(c){ case 'T': case 'A': return true; } return false;
    // ASCII is assumed
    const char m = ~0x1f;
    const char w = 'n' & ~m;
    return (c & m) | w;
}

static const unsigned threshold = N * PERCENT / 100;
// Store the input in buf
static char buf[N];
// Store the output to-be-outputted in out
static char out[N];
// The current position in buf and out
// The count of readed characters
static size_t pos;
// The count of one of searched characters in buf
static unsigned count_them;

static void buf_reset(void) {
    pos = 0;
    count_them = 0;
}
static void buf_flush(void) {
    output(out, pos);
    buf_reset();
}
static void buf_replace_them(void) {
    // TODO: this could keep count of characters alrady replaced in out to save CPU
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        if (is_one_of_them(out[i])) {
            out[i] = convert_them_to_n(out[i]);
        }
    }
}
static void buf_flush_one(void) {
    assert(pos > 0);
    assert(pos == N);
    output(out, 1);
    count_them -= is_one_of_them(buf[0]);
    memmove(buf, buf + 1, pos - 1);
    memmove(out, out + 1, pos - 1);
    pos--;
}
static void buf_add(char c) {
    buf[pos] = out[pos] = c;
    pos++;
    count_them += is_one_of_them(c);

    // if we reached the substring length
    if (pos == N) {
        // if the count reached the threshold
        if (count_them >= threshold) {
            // convert the characters to n
            buf_replace_them();
        }
        // flush one character only at a time
        buf_flush_one();
    }
}


int main() {
    int c;
    buf_reset();
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            // If its a newline, just flush what we have buffered
            buf_flush();
            output("\n", 1);
            continue;
        }
        buf_add(c);
    }
    buf_flush();
}
```

Such a C program is easily transferable to for example an `awk` script, just one need to read one character at a time. Below I split the characters with `split`, like:

```
awk -v N=10 -v percent=50 '
BEGIN{ threshold = N * percent / 100; pos=0 }

function is_one_of_them(c) {
    return c ~ /^[aAtT]$/;
}
function buf_flush(i) {
    for (i = 0; i < pos; ++i) {
        printf "%s", out[i]
    }
    pos = 0
    count_them = 0
}
function buf_replace_them(i) {
    for (i = 0; i < pos; ++i) {
        if (is_one_of_them(out[i])) {
            out[i] = out[i] ~ /[AT]/ ? "N" : "n";
        }
    }
}
function buf_flush_one(i) {
    printf "%s", out[0]
    count_them -= is_one_of_them(buf[0])

    if(0 && debug) {
    printf(" count_them %s ", count_them)
    for (i = 0; i < pos-1; ++i) {
        printf("%s", buf[i+1])
    } printf(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < pos-1; ++i) {
        printf("%s", out[i+1])
    }
    printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < pos-1; ++i) {
        buf[i] = buf[i+1]
        out[i] = out[i+1]
    }
    pos--
}
function buf_add(c) {
    buf[pos]=c; out[pos]=c; pos++
    count_them += is_one_of_them(c)

    if (pos == N) {
        if (count_them >= threshold) {
            buf_replace_them()
        }
        buf_flush_one()
    }
}
{
    split($0, chars, "")
    for (idx = 0; idx <= length($0); idx++) {
        buf_add(chars[idx])
    }
    buf_flush();
    printf "\n";
}
'
```

Both programs when run with the input presented in the first line produce the output presented in the second line (note that lone `a` near the end is not replaced, because there are no `5` charactets `ATat` in a window of `10` characters from it):

```
NNNNNNNNNNggcaaacagaatccagcagcacatcaaaaagcttatccacAGTAATTCATTATATCAAAATGCTCCAggccaggcgtggtggcttatgcc
NNNNNNNNNNggcnnncngnnnccngcngcncnncnnnnngcnnnnccncNGNNNNNCNNNNNNNCNNNNNGCNCCNggccaggcgnggnggcnnnngcc
```

[Both solutions were tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/PalegreenAliceblueErrors#main.sh).

Comment: The C part looks good, but the awk part will be very slow, array access and individual character manipulation is not nearly as fast in awk as it is in C sadly. But I would probably have done the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful with how you address this problem. You cannot work on the substituted string. You need to keep track of the original string. Here is a simple example. Assume we have a string consisting of `x` and `y` and we want to replace all `y` with `z` if there are 8 `y` in a substring of 10. Imagine your input looks like:

```
 yyyyyyyyxxy
```

The first substring of 10 reads `yyyyyyyyxx` and would be translated into `zzzzzzzzxx`. If you perform the substitution directly into the original string, you get `zzzzzzzzxxy`. The second substring now reads `zzzzzzzxxy`, and does not contain 8 times `y`, while in the original string it does. So according to the solution of the OP, this would lead into inconsistent results, depending on if you start from the front or the back. So a quick solution would be:

```
awk -v N=10 -v p=50 '
BEGIN { n = N*p/100 }
{ s = $0 }
{ for(i=1;i<=length-N;++i) {
    str=substr($0,i,N)
    c=gsub(/[AT]/,"N",str) + gsub(/[at]/,"n",str)
    if(c >= n) s = substr(s,1,i-1) str substr(s,i+N)
  }
}
{ print s }' file
```

There is ofcourse quite some work you do double here. Imagine you have a string of the form `xxyyyyyyyyxx`, you would perform 4 concatinations while you only need to do one. So the best idea is to minimalise the work and only check the substrings which end with the respective character:

```
awk -v N=10 -v p=50 '
BEGIN { n = N*p/100 }
{ s = $0 }
{ i=N; while (match(substr($0,i),/[ATat]/)) {
    str=substr($0,i+RSTART-N,N)
    c=gsub(/[AT]/,"N",str) + gsub(/[at]/,"n",str)
    if(c >= n) { s = substr(s,1,i+RSTART-N-1) str substr(s,i+RSTART)}
    i=i+RSTART
  }
}
{ print s }' file
```

Comment: I understand the logic of your script, but the expected result is not as expected.
I have another script to calculate the number of matched substr, which your script is not substituting as much as the number > rate

Answer (score 0):

To replace $0 at position i with x do:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{i=12345;x="blubber"}
{
  printf("%s",substr($0,1,i)); 
  printf("%s",x);
  printf("%s",substr($0,i+length(x)));
}'
```

I don't think there is any faster method.

To replace AGCT with N and agct with n use `tr`. To replace them only within a range and using awk you should do:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{i=12345;n=123}
{
  printf("%s",substr($0,1,i-1)); 
  printf(gsub(/[atgc]/,"n",gsub(/[ATGC]/,"N",substr($0,i,i+n-1))));
  printf("%s",substr($0,i+n));
}'
```

To do more advanced and faster processing you should consider c/c++.