# Faster algorithm/language for string replacement

Tags: awk, substring

### EDIT:

Method 3 provided below is way faster by testing, reduce the estimated runtime from `2-3` days to `< 1` day.

---

I had a sample file with a long string `>50M` like this.

```
CACTGCTGTCACCCTCCATGCACCTGCCCACCCTCCAAGGATCNNNNNNNCACTGCTGTCACCCTCCATGCACCTGCCCACCCTCCAAGGATCaagctCCgaTNNNNNNNNNNNNGgtgtgtatatatcatgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCCCTAGGGCCCTAtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCGGatgtgtggtgtgtggggttagggttagggttaNNNNNNNNNNNCCCTCCAAGGATCaagctCCgaTNNNNNNNNNNNNGgtgtgtatataGCCCTAGGtcatgtgtgatgtgtggtgtgtggggttagggttagggttaNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGCCCTAGGNNNNNNNGCCCTAGGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAGGGCCCTAGGGCCCTAtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCGGagtatatatcatgtgtgatgtgttggggtNNNNNNGgtgtgtatatatcatagggAGGGCCCTAGGGCCCTAtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCGGagtatatatcatgtgtgatgtgtggtgtgggtgtgtggggttagggAGGGCCCTAGGGCCCTAtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCGGagtatatatcatgtgtgatgtggtgtgtggggttagggttagggttaNNNNNNNNNNNNtgttgttttattttcttacaggtggtgtgtggggttagggttagggttaNNNNNNNNNNNCCCTCCAAGGATCaagctCCgaTNNNNNNNNNNNNGgtgtgtatatatcatgtAGCCCTAGGGatgtgtggtgtgtggggttagggttagggttaNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNttgtggtgtgtggtgNNNNNAGGGCtggtgtgtggggttagggAtagggAGGGCCCTAGGGCCCTAtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCGGagtatatatcatgtgtgatgtgtggtgtgtggggGGGCCCTAGGGCCCTAtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCGGagtatatatcatgtgtgatgtgtggtgtgtggggttagggNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAGaggcatattgatcCCCTCCAAGGATCaagctCCgaTNNNNNNNggttagggttNNNNNGgtgtCCCTAGGGCCCTAGGGCCCTAtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCGGagtatatatcatgtgtgatgtgtggtgtgtggggttagggttagggttaNNNNNNNNNNNNtgttgttttattttcttacaggtggtgtgtggggttagggttagggttaNNNNNNNNNNNCCCTCCAAGGATCaagctCCgaTNNNNNNNNNNNNGgtgtgtatatatcatgtAGCCCTAGGGatgtgtggtgtgtggggttagggttagggttaNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNttgtggtgtgtggtgNNNNNAGGGCCCTAGGGCCCTAtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCGGagtatatatcatgtgtgatgtgttggggtNNNNNNGgtgtgtatatatcatagggAGGGCCCTAGGGCCCTAtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCGGagtatatatcatgtgtgatgtgtggtgtgggtgtgtggggttagggAGGGCCCTAGGGCCCTAtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCtgtgtgGCCCTAGGGCGGagtatatatcatgtgtgNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

> For everything `substring` with length `k = 50` (which means there are
> `length(file)-k+1` substring)
>
> if the `A||T||a||t` (Upper & Lower case) is `>40%`,
>
> replace every character in that substring with `N` or `n` (preserving
> case).

Sample output:

```
CACTGCTGTCACCCTCCATGCACCTGCCCACCCTCCAAGGATCNNNNNNNCACTGCTGTCACCCTCCATGCACCTGCCCACCCTCCAAGGATCaagctCCgaTNNNNNNNNNNNNGgnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnggttaNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnNNnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGCCCTAGGNNNNNNNGCCCTAGGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnNNnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNttgtggtgtgtggtgNNNNNAGGNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnngggttagggNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAGaggcatattgatcCCCTCCAAGGATCaagctCCgaTNNNNNNNggttagggttNNNNNGnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnNNnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNttgtggtgtgtggtgNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnngNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

I was using `AWK` in command line for ease, but it just runs extremely slow with string replacement... and consume only <5% CPU somehow

Code: https://repl.it/@hey0wing/DutifulHandsomeMisrac-2

```
# Method 1
cat chr22.fa | head -n1 > chr22.masked.fa
cat chr22.fa | tail -n+2 | awk -v k=100 -v r=40 '{
    printf("chr22.fa: %d\n",length($0))
    i = 1;
    while (i <= length($0)-k+1) {
        x = substr($0, i, k)
        if (i == 1) {
            rate = gsub(/A/,"A",x) + gsub(/T/,"T",x) + gsub(/a/,"a",x) + gsub(/t/,"t",x)
        } else {
            prevx = substr($0,i-1,1)
            if (prevx == "A" || prevx == "a" || prevx == "T" || prevx == "t")
                rate -= 1
            nextx = substr(x,k,1)
            if (nextx == "A" || nextx == "a" || nextx == "T" || nextx == "t")
                rate += 1
        }
        if (rate>r*k/100) {
            h++
            highGC[i] = i
        }
        printf("index-r:%f%% high-AT:%d \r",i/(length($0)-k+1)*100,h)
        i += 1
    }
    printf("index-r:%f%% high-AT:%d\n\n",i/(length($0)-k+1)*100,h)
    for (j in highGC) {
        y = highGC[j]
        SUB++
        printf("sub-r:%f%% \r",SUB/h*100)
        x = substr($0, y, k)
        gsub (/[AGCT]/,"N",x)
        gsub (/[agct]/,"n",x)
        $0 = substr($0,1,y-1) x substr($0,y+k)
    }
    printf("sub-r:%f%%\nsubstituted:%d\n\n",SUB/h*100,SUB)
    printf("%s",$0) >> "chr22.masked.fa"
}'
# Method 2
cat chr22.fa | head -n1 > chr22.masked2.fa
    cat chr22.fa | tail -n+2 | awk -v k="100" -v r=40 '{
        printf("chr22.fa: %d\n",length($0))
        i = 1;
        h = 0;
        while (i<=length($0)-k+1) {
            x = substr($0, i, k)
            rate = gsub(/[ATX]/,"X",x) + gsub(/[atx]/,"x",x)
            if (rate>r/k*100) {
                h++
                gsub (/[GC]/,"N",x)
                gsub (/[gc]/,"n",x)
                $0 = substr($0,1,i-1) x substr($0,i+k)
            }
            printf("index-r:%f%% sub-r:%f%% \r",i/(length($0)-k+1)*100,h/544*100)
            i += 1
        }
        gsub (/X/,"N",$0)
        gsub (/x/,"n",$0)
        printf("index-r:%f%% sub-r:%f%% \n",i/(length($0)-k+1)*100,h/544*100)
        printf("%s",$0) >> "chr22.masked2.fa"
    }'

# Method 3
cat chr22.fa | head -n1 > chr22.masked3.fa
cat chr22.fa | tail -n+2 | awk -v k="100" -v r=40 '{
    printf("chr22.fa: %d\n",length($0))
    i = 1;
    h = 0;
    while (i <= length($0)-k+1) {
        x = substr($0, i, k)
        rate = gsub(/A/,"A",x) + gsub(/T/,"T",x) + gsub(/a/,"a",x) + gsub(/t/,"t",x)
        if (rate>r/k*100) {
          h++
          gsub(/[ACGT]/,"N",x)
          gsub(/[acgt]/,"n",x)
          if (i == 1) {
            s = x
          } else {
            s = substr(s,1,length(s)-k+1) x
          }
        } else  {
          if (i == 1) {
            s = x
          } else {
            s = s substr(x,k,1)
          }
        }
        printf("index-r:%f%% sub-r:%f%% \r",i/(length($0)-k+1)*100,h/544*100)
        i += 1
    }
    printf("index-r:%f%% sub-r:%f%% \n\n",i/(length($0)-k+1)*100,h/544*100)
    printf("%s",s) >> "chr22.masked3.fa"
}'
```

The estimated runtime is around 2-3 days ...

Are there any faster algorithm for this problem? If no, are there any language can perform string replacement faster?

**More info:**
the `AWK` command consume `~30%` CPU at `WSL` & `GitBash`, but only `~5%` on windows `cmd` with an `OpenSSH` client, where the progress rate is similar

Comment: Edited, this is the simpler method I used. Another similar method I tried is in the link

Comment: Code like `$0 = substr($0,1,i-1) x substr($0,i+k)` is most likely going to be horrendously expensive, and `printf()` every character seems excessive. If this code is working, posting to [codereview.se] is usually better. Personally speaking, I'd rewrite this in Python.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on [codereview.se].

Comment: The `printf()` is for tracking the progress of this problem... I had the code ran for 6 hours and wonder when it would end. I will re-post the same question on code review, thanks.

Comment: @thanasisp the result should be `nnnnnn`, so my code would replace all `a` with `x` first, include the count of `x` when calculating the percentage, and replace all `x` with `n` at the very end

Comment: just added more code, and trying out the `method 3` now

Comment: Your sample output is incorrect. It also replaces other characters by `n` or `N` (you can see this in the end of the example input/output)

Comment: @kvantour The problem is to replace `EVERY` character in the substring. BTW, I had asked the same question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249422/faster-algorithm-language-for-substring-sliding-window-replacement?noredirect=1#comment488971_249422), added a new `method 4`.

Comment: @thanasisp I misunderstood the requirement of this problem in the first place, and asked with a wrong requirement. 

Sorry for ignoring the answers, but the question there is too chaotic with many uncertainty and changes, so everybody is basically answering different questions with different test cases and different requirements. Then, I decided to reorganize the whole question, provide more information with test case and code, and repost it here.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, there's an `O(n)` solution that involves a sliding window on to your data set. The following algorithm should suffice:

```
set window to ""
while true:
    if window is "":
        read k characters into window, exit while if less available
        set atCount to number of characters in window matching "AaTt".
    if atCount > 40% of k:
        for each char in window:
            if char uppercase:
                output "N"
            else:
                output "n"
        window = ""
    else:
        if first character of window matches "AaTt":
            decrease atCount
        remove first character of window
        read next character into end of window, exit while if none available
        if last character of window matches "AaTt":
            increase atCount
```

What this does is to run a sliding window through your data, at each point testing if the proportion of `AaTt` characters in that window is more than 40%.

If so, it outputs the desired `Nn` characters and reloads the next k-sized window.

If it's *not* over 40%, it removes the first character in the windows and adds the next one to the end, adjusting the count of `AaTt` characters correctly.

If, at any point, there aren't enough characters left to satisfy a check (`k` when loading a full window, or `1` when sliding), it exits the loop.

Comment: I tried this method and implemented in the code link, which does not matter a lot in my question. The critical element of speed is the rewrite of input string `$0 = substr($0,1,i-1) x substr($0,i+k)`

Comment: @hey0god: I'm not sure `awk` is the best tool for this job, and string substitutions probably aren't helping much either (in the speed department). Python would probably be a better choice if you want to stick to an easy scripting language. Otherwise C or C++ for raw speed may be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try some perl:

```sh
perl -slpe '
    my $len = length;
    for (my $i = 0; $i < $len; $i += $k) {
        my $substring = substr($_, $i, $k);
        my $count = $substring =~ tr/aAtT/aAtT/;
        if ($count >= $k * $threshold) {
            $substring =~ s/[[:lower:]]/n/g;
            $substring =~ s/[[:upper:]]/N/g;
            substr($_, $i, $k) = $substring;
        }
    }
' -- -k=50 -threshold=0.4 file
```